# Add 2 watermark with scale2ref 40 percent width of video and timeout using FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

Add 2 watermark with scale2ref 40 percent width of video and timeout using FFmpeg

timeout for the top right corner (first 8 sec) then the bottom right corner till the end time.

`ffmpeg -i 1597739850_368007908.mp4 -i artistsharleen.png -i artistsharleen.png -filter_complex "[1][0scale2ref=w='iw*40/100':h='ow/mdar'[wm][vid];[vid][wm]overlay=10:40:enable='between(t,0,8)'"[v1];[v1][2]scale2ref=w='iw*40/100':h='ow/mdar'[a][b];[b][a]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable='gt(t,8)[v2]" -map "[v2]" -map 0:a 17780739871599156232.mp4`

I'm able to place 2 watermarks with keyframe

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image2.png -i image2.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,0,8)'[v1];[v1][2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable='gt(t,8)'[v2]" -map "[v2]" -map 0:a output.mp4`

but my images are not getting scaled as per video resolution, that's why i want to integrate scale2ref in this command

Hope someone also faces this problem, can help me.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @llogan, I'm able to place 2 watermarks with keyframe ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image2.png -i image2.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,0,8)'[v1];[v1][2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10:enable='gt(t,8)'[v2]" -map "[v2]" -map 0:a
output.mp4
but my images are not getting scaled as per video resolution, that I want to integrate scale2ref in this command